# Is there a way to know how much a Sony mirrorless camera was used for video?

Tags: sensor, video, mirrorless

I'm willing to buy an "as new" A6000 from someone who said to have quit photography and used this same A6000 for 2 recordings only. I can't visit the seller to see it for myself and I'd have three days to check it out before I could open a complaint (on the online store, against the seller).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from my sony alpha (5100 - mostly same internals), there's no 'obvious' setting that shows "lifetime" recording/usage statistics. There's a media information menu but that shows shots/time remaining on the SD card

Can't really find a debug menu type thing - assuming that someone servicing the camera would be interested in that, which would be a natural place to store this kind of thing.

Answer (score -1):

You can count the number of *shutter actuations* (images taken) with the [SONY Alpha shutter count tool](http://tools.science.si/index.php). It takes an original jpeg or raw image, and reads its EXIF metadata.

Note that eventually the counter is not set to zero even when it's new. The manufacturer might do some tests after the counter is set to zero and ON.

UPDATE

I cannot investigate videos EXIF, but at least you can tell if the person used heavily for photographs or not.

In any case, the camera doesn't grow old / loose its abilities by being used with video. Only the mechanical shutter grows old and the Li battery (when left discharged).

Comment: What effect does taking a video have on the shutter count?

Comment: and in theory, rather than uploading one of your photographs, you might be able to do it with exif tool - since that's what this seems to be doing

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You got the idea. It's in the EXIF.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Didn't try to get the EXIF from video. The point is that you can tell at least if the camera was used in some extent for photographs. I think if it's not a full answer, it's a step forward.

Comment: video dosen't do exif iirc. I *think* there might be some container specific tagging but lifetime recording time dosen't seem something it would have...

Comment: poked around a video file from my camera - and here's a dump of the metadata from a video https://pastebin.com/nsNiH2jh using mediainfo. Nothing that tasty there

Comment: Can you access to batteries info ? With Canon LPE6 batteries, there is a count for images taken, but not video; also there is a metric about *charge ability*. Supposing batteries are the one from the package, and the only ones that were used.

The actuation number will nevertheless give you a clue about the camera usage.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell Assuming the A6000 and A5100 work similarly (and they share a lot of internals - and no, no real way for me to find shutter count or get battery information that I can find.

Comment: @Soleil The shutter count with Canon batteries, such as the LP-E6, is reset to zero each time it is recharged by a Canon charger (or third party charger that emulates such a Canon charger.)

Comment: Doesn't recording heat the sensor (and many other parts of the camera) much more? It's completely safe?

Comment: @rsb2097 the only dangerous thing for the sensor is not its usage with visible light but (powerful) lasers (eg., lasers from music shows etc).